# Init state function is being called multiple times from within the same screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

The init state method is being called automatically many times even when not navigating.
The logs are showing that the Init State is being called multiple times:

> D/InputMethodManager( 6287): HSIFW - flag : 0 D/InsetsSourceConsumer(
> 6287): setRequestedVisible: visible=false, type=13,
> host=com.example.k9_groceries/com.example.k9_groceries.MainActivity,
> from=android.view.InsetsSourceConsumer.hide:236
> android.view.ImeInsetsSourceConsumer.hide:101
> android.view.InsetsController.hideDirectly:1430
> android.view.InsetsController.controlAnimationUnchecked:1112
> android.view.InsetsController.applyAnimation:1417
> android.view.InsetsController.hide:984
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage:6150
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:106 android.os.Looper.loop:246
> android.app.ActivityThread.main:8653  D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 6287):
> The input method toggled cursor monitoring off
> D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 6287): The input method toggled text
> monitoring off I/SurfaceControl( 6287): nativeRelease nativeObject
> s[-5476376663174376064] I/SurfaceControl( 6287): nativeRelease
> nativeObject e[-5476376663174376064] [Log] CALLBACK INIT STATE A [Log]
> CALLBACK INIT STATE

**Please look at the code below**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:k9_groceries/custom/iconBtn.dart';
import 'package:k9_groceries/utils/constants.dart';
import '../utils/Services.dart';
import '../utils/categories.dart';
import '../utils/product.dart';
import '../custom/product.dart';
import 'package:easy_debounce/easy_debounce.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {

  bool _loading = true;
  bool _loadingCategories = true;
  String _category = "all";
  late List<Products> _products;
  late List<CategoryItem> _categories;
  late String _searchText;
  final TextEditingController _searchController  = TextEditingController();
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    developer.log('CALLBACK INIT STATE A', name: 'Log');

    _searchText = "";
    _products = <Products>[];
    _loading = true;
    _loadingCategories = false;
    _categories = <CategoryItem>[] ;
    developer.log('CALLBACK INIT STATE', name: 'Log');
    Services.getProducts(_category, "").then((products) {
      setState(() {
        _products = products;
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
    Categories.getCategories().then((categories) {
      _categories = categories;
      setState(() {
        _loadingCategories = false;
      });
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    callback(category) {

      setState(() {
        _category = category;
        _products = <Products>[];
        _loading = false;
        var searchItem =  _searchText ;
        Services.getProducts(_category, searchItem).then((products) {
          developer.log('CALLBACK 456', name: 'Log');

          setState(() {
            _products = products;
            _loading = false;
          });
        });
      });
    }

    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final double pading = 10;


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: whiteColor,
        title:    Text(_loading ? "Loading...": "K9 Mart", style: themeData.textTheme.headline1),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
          child: Column(

            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

            children: [
               Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: [
                   Expanded(
                     child: search(themeData),
                   ),
              
              
                 ],
               ),
              (_categories.isNotEmpty)
                  ? Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                height: 120,
                child: GridView.builder(

                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 1,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                      childAspectRatio: 1,
                      mainAxisExtent: 120,


                    ),

                    itemCount: null == _categories ? 0 : _categories.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      CategoryItem category = _categories[index];
                      return (
                          scrollBtn(
                              category.name,
                              callback,
                              category.img
                          )
                      );
                    }
                ),
              )
                  : Text('', style: themeData.textTheme.headline6,),
              Flexible(
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                child: GridView.builder(
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                      childAspectRatio: 0.5,
                    ),
                    itemCount: null == _products ? 0 : _products.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Products product = _products[index];
                      return (
                          ProductItem(
                            uom: product.uom,
                            id: product.id,
                            image: product.img,
                            price: product.price,
                            name: product.name,
                            description: product.description,
                            sellingPrice: product.sellingPrice,
                            quantity: product.quantity,
                          )
                      );
                    }
                ),
              )

            ],

          ),
        ),
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.list),
            label: 'Categories',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            label: 'Cart',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search ),
            label: 'Search',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Account',
          ),
        ],
        // currentIndex: _se ,
        selectedItemColor: whiteColor ,
        // onTap: (){},
      ),
    );


  }

  TextField search(themeData){
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (n){
        developer.log("AA CHANGED $n" );
        _searchText = n;
      },
      onSubmitted: (a){
        developer.log("AA Submitted $a");
      },
      onEditingComplete: (){
        developer.log("AA Editing ");
      },
      autofocus: false,
      obscureText: false,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Search atta, dal, coke, ....',
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0x00000000),
            width: 1,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0x00000000),
            width: 1,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      style: themeData.textTheme.bodyText1,
    );
  }

}

class scrollBtn extends StatefulWidget {
  String text;
  Function(String) callback;
  String url;

  scrollBtn(this.text, this.callback, this.url);

  @override
  _scrollBtnState createState() => _scrollBtnState();
}

class _scrollBtnState extends State<scrollBtn> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return  Container(
        height: 120,
        width: 120,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: greyColor,
        ),
        padding: const  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap:() {
            developer.log('CALLBACK 789', name: 'Log');
            widget.callback(widget.text); //call to parent
          },
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Image.network(widget.url, width: 60, height: 60,),
              Text(
                widget.text, style: themeData.textTheme.headline6,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }


}
```

"CALLBACK INIT STATE A" is being logged multiple times in the same screen.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `init` called multiple times it just means that your widget tree changed. The root cause should be somewhere above the tree.

I see that you are abusing `seState` in the build method if the same exists in the widget tree above that can be the root cause of why your state reinitializing every time.